# Add specific word before the category page title

Tags: categories, wp-title

in my site category page (archive page), the page title in browser is like this:

**My site | Site Description | Category title**

How i can add specific word befor all of category title.
like:

**My site | Site Description | *My word* Category title**

Answer (score 1):

Since WP 4.4 you can change document title using `document_title_parts` filter hook, in earlier versions it will be `wp_title_parts` (since v4.0) or `wp_title` filter.

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'se333744_site_title' );
function se333744_site_title( $title )
{
    if ( isset($title['title']) && strlen($title['title']) && !is_front_page() && is_archive() )
        $title['title'] = ' {some prefix} ' . $title['title'];
    return $title;
}
```