# change title page on search result

Tags: php, title

I want to change in my search result the title. Unfortunately I don't have option to change this in , because I must do it in plugin file.

Actually I have that code in PHP file:

```
if (isset($_GET['search_region']) ) {
    if (isset($_GET['search_region']) ) {
        foreach ($cat as $catid => $categories) {
            foreach ($city as $idRegion => $region) {
                if ($_GET['search_categories'] == $catid && $_GET['search_region'] == $idRegion) {
                    printf('<h1 class="cat-title">%s %s</h1>', $categories, $region);

                    **
                    ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.title = "<?php printf('%s %s', $categories, $region); ?>";
                    </script>
                    <?php
                    **
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

Everything is good, bad is only this what is between **. It would be fine but it only changing title on page bar, in the page code  is unchanged.
Do you have any idea how I can changing title in  in this space?

Comment: [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/333744/add-specific-word-before-the-category-page-title/333748#333748) should work for you. You just have to change the *IF* condition and use `is_search()` in it.

Comment: @nmr can you try implemented this in my code and write in question? please. In addition I inform, that this code I have in is_archive()

Answer (score 1):

To change document title use `document_title_parts`.filter. You want to apply changes only on the search page (as indicated in the title), so you should use `is_search()` [conditional tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) (or `is_archive()` as you suggest in the comment) and your code from php file.

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'se333744_site_title' );
function se333744_site_title( $title )
{
    global $wp_query;
    if ( is_archive() )
    {
        // your code here
        if ( isset($_GET['search_region'], $_GET['search_categories']) ) 
        {
            // set variables: $cat, $city
            //
            foreach ($cat as $catid => $categories) {
                foreach ($city as $idRegion => $region) {

                    if ( $catid == $_GET['search_categories'] &&  
                        $idRegion == $_GET['search_region']) 
                    {
                        $title['title'] = sprintf("%s %s", $categories, $region);
                        return $title;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

---

I don't know your code so I may be wrong, but code that determine document name I would move to a function. Being in one place, it will be easier to manage.. Thanks to the static variable, the code will be executed only once, and subsequent function calls will return the previously determined title.
Function `se333874_prepare_title` you use in `se333744_site_title` and in PHP file.

functions.php

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'se333744_site_title' );
function se333744_site_title( $title )
{
    global $wp_query;
    if ( is_search() )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['search_region'], $_GET['search_categories']) ) 
            $title['title'] = se333874_prepare_title();
    }
    return $title;
}

function se333874_prepare_title()
{
    static $title = null;
    if ( $title != null)
        return $title;

    $title = false;
    if ( isset($_GET['search_region'], $_GET['search_categories']) ) 
    {
        // set $cat and $city variables here
        //
        foreach ($cat as $catid => $categories) {
            foreach ($city as $idRegion => $region) {

                if ( $catid == $_GET['search_categories'] &&  
                    $idRegion == $_GET['search_region']) 
                {
                    $title = sprintf("%s %s", $categories, $region);
                    return $title;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

PHP file:

```
if ( isset($_GET['search_region'], $_GET['search_categories']) ) 
    printf('<h1 class="cat-title">%s %s</h1>', $categories, $region);
```